# Multiple valid answers for a form

Tags: php, validation

I am using an contact form and I am really in need of this. I sent message to developer but I cannot wait any longer...

I tried many things to make it work, but failed always. No matter what I do, either none is valid answer, or only first one or only last one... So please php programmers, help me with this problem.

```
$custom = new Quform_Element('custom_answer', 'Custom answer');
$custom->addFilter('trim');
$custom->addValidator('required');
$custom->addValidator('identical', array(
'token' => 'im-a-test',
'messages' => array(
'not_match' => 'Invalid Answer. Please try again!'
)
));
$custom->setIsHidden(true);
$form->addElement($custom);
```

Basically its like custom validator field. So there is form where people type something...
How to make multiple identical valid answers? im-a-test works, but how to add im-a-test2 and so on... I want like 20 correct answers.

If anyone can help me with this, I truly appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Quform_Element is based on Zend_Form_Element. If it is, and the rest of Zend Framework is there, then this might work:

```
$custom->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_InArray(array('im-a-test', 'im-a-test-2')));
```

Comment: yep its correct... I will try within 30 mins ;) ! I hope it works.

Comment: Wish I know what Zend is... I use Quform: 
http://codecanyon.net/item/quform-simple-yet-powerful-ajax-contact-form/148273

And I cannot find anything about multiple valid answers even in documentation.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like it wants to be Zend, but isn't it exactly, so my answer won't work. You could try this: `$custom->addValidator('inarray', array(array('im-a-test', 'im-a-test2')));`. That would imitate the style above. Without the full source, though, I'm afraid I can't help any more.

Comment: Well if you have skype or something, I would really appreciate. If not, oh well thanks for trying :) ! I will mark as an answer, cause I doubt anyone will answer. If you have skype , cool... dvLden is my skype!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I don't have time to really delve into it, but I hope you figure it out.